# Problems with Gradle when updating

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle

Updated from Android studio 2.3.3 to 3.0
Imported my project and got this error:

```
Program type already present: com.google.firebase.iid.zzd
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.google.firebase.iid.zzd, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'




    //Optionally configure your OneSignal IDs below
    manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId: "${applicationId}",
                            onesignal_app_id: "",
                            onesignal_google_project_number: ""]
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
dexOptions {
    jumboMode true
}
}

repositories {
flatDir {
    dirs 'libs'
}
maven {
    url "https://jitpack.io"
}
jcenter();
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.devbrackets.android:exomedia:4.0.3' //TV
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.4.3' //TV & Radio
compile 'com.cleveroad:audiovisualization:1.0.0' //Radio
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0' //WC
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0' //WC
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.5,4.0.0)'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.booking:rtlviewpager:1.0.1'
compile 'com.github.apg-mobile:android-round-textview:v0.0.3'
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.3.0'

compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportlib_version"
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportlib_version"
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportlib_version"
compile "com.android.support:design:$supportlib_version"
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportlib_version"
compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:$supportlib_version"
compile "com.android.support:support-media-compat:$supportlib_version"

compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$gps_version"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$gps_version"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$gps_version"
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't take too long to find the solution to the problem. I had to update my $gps_version to the latest and project works fine and error disappeared

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$gps_version"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$gps_version"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$gps_version"
```